# How can i find out the last entered object in an array of objects, where similar objects can be entered multiple times

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, object

Suppose,
i have an object with properties, `details : {"name","id"}` , now there is an array that holds collection of details. now suppose , an object with `{name:max, id:55}` is pushed in the array more than once. how do i find out the last entered `{name:max,id:55}` from that array using TypeScript .

Comment: data[data.length-1]

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with pure JavaScript and `lastIndexOf`:

```js
const myArray = [{
  name: "max",
  id: 55
}, {
  name: "john",
  id: 13
}, {
  name: "susan",
  id: "123"
}, {
  name: "max",
  id: 55
}];

const lastEntered = (name, id) => {
    var matches = myArray.filter(e => e.name == name && e.id == id);
    return matches.length - 1;
}

console.log(lastEntered("max", 55));
```

Comment: That is returning -1

Comment: Sorry @PrashantZombade, will fix.

Comment: This is wrong. First of all, from the question, the user wants lastly added object, not index. And even if you are returning index, it should return 3 considering example shown in answer code. Lastly, in answer heading, you have written to use `lastIndexOf`, but you are using `filter`.

Answer (score 0):

Array is last in first out data structure.

So the last in element will occupy the element with the largest index.

So you may get the element by `array[array.length-1]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use reduce to change the array to an object, where the key is a value from the object, and the value is the last index of that key.

```
const details = [{ name: 'max', id: 55 }];
const detailsMap = details.reduce((acc, person, index) => {
  acc[person.id] = index;
  return acc;
}, {});
const lastIndexOfMax = detailsMap[55];
```

Here we set the id from the detail object to the key (because I assumed that each id is unique). When we enter that key into the details map, it returns to use the index of the array where that id is last located.